# How to configure transaction management for different read/write data sources in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

We are using Spring Batch with 2 data sources: 1 for reading (source db), 1 for writing (destination db).

Spring Batch is configured to use the destination data source/transaction manager for the `JobRepository` and `JobExplorer`:

```java
@EnableBatchProcessing(transactionManagerRef = "destinationTransactionManager", dataSourceRef = "destinationDataSource")
```

For the job config, `JpaCursorItemReader` is configured to use the `EntityManagerFactory` that belongs to the source db (with a `PlatformTransactionManager` belonging to the source db).

`JpaItemWriter` is configured to use the `EntityManagerFactory` and `PlatformTransactionManager` that belongs to the destination db. This `PlatformTransactionManager` is the same one that is being used in `@EnableBatchProcessing`.

Our chunk-oriented step uses the `PlatformTransactionManager` that belongs to the destination db (the same one that is being used in `@EnableBatchProcessing`).

My question is: is this a correct setup (especially regarding transaction management)? It hasn't been giving us any problems so far. I'm a bit concerned since the reader side uses a different data source.

My assumption is that this should work, since the `PlatformTransactionManager` of the chunk is the same one that is being used for the `JobRepository` and `JpaItemWriter`. So I'm assuming that when something fails, rollbacking progress (in the metadata tables) and written items should at least work, since they are using the same data source and transaction manager. Moreover, `JpaCursorItemReader` doesn't seem to be transaction aware.

Our configuration looks like this (slightly modified to omit domain language):

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableBatchProcessing(transactionManagerRef = "destinationTransactionManager", dataSourceRef = "destinationDataSource")
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public JpaCursorItemReader<SourceEntity> sourceReader(
        @Qualifier("sourceEntityManagerFactory") final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sourceEntityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaCursorItemReaderBuilder<SourceEntity>()
            .name("SourceEntity")
            .entityManagerFactory(Objects.requireNonNull(sourceEntityManagerFactory.getObject()))
            .queryString("from SourceEntity")
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaItemWriter<DestinationEntity> destinationWriter(
        @Qualifier("destinationEntityManagerFactory")
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean destinationEntityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaItemWriterBuilder<DestinationEntity>()
            .entityManagerFactory(Objects.requireNonNull(destinationEntityManagerFactory.getObject()))
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(
        @Qualifier("sourceReader") final JpaCursorItemReader<SourceEntity> reader,
        @Qualifier("destinationWriter") final JpaItemWriter<DestinationEntity> writer,
        final CustomProcessor processor, // implementation omitted for brevity
        @Qualifier("destinationTransactionManager") final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
        final JobRepository jobRepository
    ) {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
            .<SourceEntity, DestinationEntity>chunk(10, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(final Step step,
                   final JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step)
            .end()
            .build();
    }
}
```

This works as expected, but I want to know if this is a correct setup regarding tx management.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of configurations, (reading/writing from/to different data sources, or writing to two different transactional resources), the biggest risk is that your business data and technical meta-data get out of sync in case of failure.

What you need to do is configure Spring Batch with a `JtaTransactionManager` that coordinates the transactions managers of all transactional resources involved in the same step.

What Spring Batch guarantees if correctly configured, is that the reader, writer and job repository interactions are executed in the same transaction, so that both business data and technical meta-data get committed or rolled back as a unit.

Comment: But in this scenario, business data and technical meta-data both use the same `PlatformTransactionManager`. Only the reader side is using a different transaction manager. Does it matter, in that case?

Comment: When you configure a single `JtaTransactionManager`, as mentioned in the answer, both the reader and the writer will be in the same transaction. The entire step's tasklet (which involves the reader, processor, writer, etc) is executed in the same transaction.

Comment: Is it necessary that the reader is in the same transaction? The current behavior is working for us fine (reader using a different tx manager - and writer / Spring Batch metadata tables using the same tx manager). I want to avoid using JTA if possible.